# servlet programmatically set authentication

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-8, keycloak, servlet-3.0

In a JAVA EE 7 web application (WAR), need to **"manually" set the user as authenticated** (with its roles).

Basically I have a token (JWT) and a set of roles (obtained after calling the Keycloak authorization client Java API).

After I get the token would like to set the user as authenticated (create the security context) so any call to a secured URL will not return 403 HTTP error.

Have defined in the web.xml just the roles and security contraints for the different URL mappings.

Haved looked into the HttpServletRequest.authenticate method but have not login-config mechanism (not need to) defined.

(not using Spring or other framework).

My guess is this is not possible and should use servlet filters to verify the security (not security-constraint in the web.xml)

Thanks

Comment: Keycloak provides authenticators for this purpose like `KeycloakJettyAuthenticator` if you are using `Jetty`. Why do you need to **manually** mark user as authentciated?

Comment: The WAR is deployed in Wildfly. Need to set the security context so can secure a set of URLs in the web.xml. (Guess is possible to use filters or other solutions but neede to try first this approach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial solution was to create a servlet filter which returns UNAUTHORIZED if the JWT token (coming in an Authorization header) does not have the required role.

A bit better approach is to create a unique filter that creates the security context on each request that requires authorization. With this I can a use a @RolesAllowed annotation.

For the RolesAllowed annotation to work (otherwise all requests are allowed) it is important to add in the **web.xml**:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I can't define any auth-constraints in the web.xml , otherwise the application returns 403 Forbidden before the filter even gets called.

**SECURITY FILTER:**

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        SecurityContext originalContext = requestContext.getSecurityContext();

        // 1. Get token from the request header: "Authorization: Bearer ..."
        String token = httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization").substring(7);

        // 2. Parse the token to an AccessToken
        // calls a utility class which uses org.keycloak.TokenVerifier to get the access token
        AccessToken accessToken = KeyCloakUtils.getAccessToken(token);

        // 3.- Obtain username and roles
        String username = accessToken.getPreferredUsername(); 
        Set<String> roles = accessToken.getRealmAccess().getRoles();

        SecurityContext sc = new SecurityContext() {
            @Override
            public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                return new User(username);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
                return roles.contains(role);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isSecure() {
                return originalContext.isSecure();
            }

            @Override
            public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
                return "Your Scheme";
            } 
        };
        requestContext.setSecurityContext(sc);
    }
}
```

Example of secured method (interface):

```
@POST
@Consumes({ "application/json" })
@Produces({ "application/json" })
@RolesAllowed({"ADMIN_USER"})
public Response createUser(User user);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a login-config. It is necessary for the servlet container.
Put something like:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>default</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

in your web.xml and HttpServletRequest.authenticate should work.

And you should remove the security constraints for this servlet
since you manage the security in the application if not already done.

Kind regards,

Ralph

Comment: that gives "javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010031: Login failed", as don´t have any security domain setup (not needed).